# Compare a N x 2 2D array row wise with 1 x 2 array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider an array:

```
array([[  0,   0],
        [  0,   0],
        [  0,   0],
        [  0, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255,   0],
        [  0,   0],
        [  0,   0],
        [  0,   0],
        [  0,   0],
        [  0, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255,   0],
        [  0,   0],
        [  0,   0]], dtype=uint8))
```

I would like to compare this with `[255, 0]` and get an output like this:

```
array([False,
       False,
       False,
       False,
       False,
       False,
        True,
       False,
       False,
       False,
       False,
       False,
       False,
        True,
       False,
       False])
```

How can I achieve this using numpy, because when I perform `arr == [255, 0]`, the shape that I get is (N, 2), meaning it is an element wise comparision:

```
array([[False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True]])
```

What I tried was to using `np.apply_along_axis` function with `np.logical_and`, but since the and function takes two arguments, my row is considered as one argument, therefore it gives an invalid argument error:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.logical_and(x), 1, arr==[255,0])
Value Error: Invalid number of arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.all(arr == [255, 0], axis=1)
```

Output

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False])
```